# Consulo IDE + ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have found Consulo IDE project here - https://github.com/consulo and I am really fascinated about the amount of work done there. C# projects working just fine with both Mono and .NET Core.

Unfortunately, I cannot make web projects. I have manually installed ASP.NET plugin from https://github.com/consulo/consulo-aspnet (copied aspnet.jar to plugins/aspnet/lib), yet it does not starts to support .aspx extensions.

Does anyone know how to make asp.net to work with consulo?
Thanks.